# Ethereum Price - Transaction cost relation

Tags: gas-price, fees, price

The average transaction cost is around 0.0005ETH which is around 0.06$ right now.
Does it mean that the transaction fee decreases whenever the price of Ethereum drops?
Isn’t the price closely related to the global adoption of Ethereum?
I find it weird that the more Ethereum gets popular, the more its price rises, and the more the transaction fee costs. Is that the main scalability issue of ethereum?